# Routes in form models/id/name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to setup slugs to have urls like this:
`/artists/1/pink-floyd`

My to_param method is:

```
  def to_param
    "#{self.id}/#{self.name.parameterize}"
  end
```

Unfortunately url is `/artists/1%2Fpink-floyd`
How can I make this work the way I want?

Comment: That doesn't work because its trying to make it url safe another `/` would indicate a different directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a number of ways.

I think what would be the closest to what you want to achieve is something like:

```
def to_param
  "#{self.id}-#{self.name.parameterize}"
end
```

Which makes:

`/artists/1-pink-floyd`

---

An alternative would be to change the routes:

`get "/artists/:id/:parameterized_name" => "artists#show", as: :artist`

This will give you params `:parameterized_name` in your controller action.

To use it in the view:

`artist_path(artist, parameterized_name: artist.name.parameterize)`

Comment: What if I use resources in routes ?